# PHP function giving me exception when trying to display on HTML

Tags: php, html, mysql, pdo

I am having issues executing an SQL statement and printing the results on my HTML page.

This is the function:

```
function getFirstName($shId) {


$query  = 'SELECT sh_firstname';
$query .= 'FROM Shaddr';
$query .= 'WHERE shopper_id = ?';

$dbo = db_connect();

try {
    $statement = $dbo->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(1,$shId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
    die("Errors encountered while obtaining first name");
}

return $statement;
}
```

and this is how i'm trying to show it in my HTML:

```
<?php 
$results = getFirstName(2);
echo $results;
?>
```

The database is connected properly and everything as I have other working queries. The error i'm getting is the exception I made "Errors encountered while obtaining first name".

What is wrong with this function?

Comment: What does your [tag:mysql] table look like?

Comment: You'd get a better error message if you look into the error log.

Comment: Next time output the real error or at least review your error log and get the real error message from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `space before FROM and WHERE` clause

```
$query  = 'SELECT sh_firstname';
$query .= ' FROM Shaddr';
$query .= ' WHERE shopper_id = ?';
```

You need to return result set from your `getFirstName()`

```
 try {
    $statement = $dbo->prepare($query);
    $statement->bindParam(1,$shId,PDO::PARAM_INT);
    $statement->execute();
}
catch (PDOException $ex) {
    error_log($ex->getMessage());
    die("Errors encountered while obtaining first name");
}

return $result = $statement->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

And you get your value as

```
<?php 
$results = getFirstName(2);
print_r($results);
?>
```

Comment: That is giving me this:

Catchable fatal error: Object of class PDOStatement could not be converted to string in /home/ubuntu/workspace/delivery_details.php on line 27 Call Stack: 0.0001 232800 1. {main}() /home/ubuntu/workspace/delivery_details.php:0

Comment: Where is your `db_connect()` function??

Comment: I believe the error is with this line:    
echo $results;   since without it the page doesn't get an error (but of course nothing from the query shows)

Comment: Amazing thanks!! It does now show "Array ( [sh_firstname] => Jane )" instead of just Jane but I will figure that out.